# Easy Way to Solve $7^{99} \pmod {125}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Naturally, one could do this with a calculator pretty easily, but is there a trick, or something you may notice, to calculate this easily by hand?

I know $\phi{125} = 100$, so could I perhaps use that somehow? I *feel* like I can, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: i got $18$ $\mod$ 125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that $7^{100}\equiv 1$, by Euler's theorem, we get that $7^{99}\equiv 7^{-1}$, so you could search for numbers on the form $125n+1$ which are divisible by $7$, and once you find one, divide it by seven and you will have your answer.

Of course, we have $125n+1\equiv -n+1 \pmod7$, which makes the search simple.

**Alternate solution** (brute force) The way computers compute powers is to do what is called *repeated squares*. You can calculate $7^2=49$. Then you can square that to make $7^4=49^2\equiv26$. Then you can square that again to get $7^8\equiv 26^2\equiv 51$, and so on. Then you use that $$7^{99}=7^{64+32+2+1}=7^{64}7^{32}7^27^1$$ to calculate the power with relatively few multiplications.

Comment: forgive my ignorance--modular arithmetic has never been my strong suit. Could you explain where the $125n + 1$ is coming from? Again, my apologies, but I would not necessarily know how to implement the method you mention in a test situation (and I feel that that's the mark of truly *knowing it*)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JohnL. You want an $x$ such that $7x\equiv 1\pmod{125}$. All numbers that are $\equiv1\pmod{125}$ are on the form $125n+1$. That means that we want an $x$ such that there is an $n$ with $7x=125n+1$. In that case we have $x=\frac{125n+1}{7}$. Remembering that everything has to be integers, we have to make sure that $n$ is such that the fraction becomes an integer, and therefore we search for a specific $n$ such that...

Comment: ahhh thank you so much! I really appreciate you laying it all out for me--seriously, for some reason mods just tend to go over my head most of the time lol

Comment: @JohnL. No problem. It definitely takes practice to get the feel for things.

Comment: If you will humor me just a moment, so as to make sure I understand this:
clearly, n=1 => x = 18. So now I know that [18] = [7]^-1, but now how might I make use of this in my initial equation? Again, you've already answered enough, so if you don't wish to explain I completely understand! But I just want to know how I'd now use that information in the equation $7^{99} \equiv 7^{-1}$

Comment: @JohnL. You already know now that $7^{-1}\equiv 18$. Now you need to tell that $7^{-1}\equiv 7^{99}$, is that right? Well, Euler's theorem tells you that $7^{100}\equiv 1$ (because $\phi(125)=100$), which means that $7\cdot 7^{99}\equiv 1$. But that is the defining property of $7^{-1}$, so the two must be the same.

Comment: oh my goodness, now I feel silly for not seeing that. Thank you SO MUCH! Seriously, you really helped me out, and I really appreciate it!

Comment: @JohnL. It is important to note that $\gcd(7,125)=1$, though. If you have a similar problem where that is not the case (say $6^{140}\pmod{100}$ or similar), you will need to be more careful, factoring wherever possible and so on. It's not really more difficult, just more to do.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you so much, again!